# Find the area of ​the parallelogram $ABCD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In a parallelogram $ABCD$ the diagonals intersect at $O$. The distances from $O$ to sides $BC$ and $CD$ measure $2$ and $3$ respectively. Calculate the area of ​​the parallelogram if $\angle ABC = 135^o$ (Answer:$24\sqrt2$)

My progess:

[image]

$S_{BCD}= \frac{BC.2}{2}=BC\\
S_{OCD} = \frac{CD.3}2=\frac{3CD}{2}\\
S_{BOC}=S_{COD} \implies BC = \frac{3CD}{2}\\
S_{ABCD} = 4BC = 6CD$

...ome detail is missing and I didn't see the given angle function

Comment: Drop perp from $D$ to $BC$, it is two times $OE$. Now given angle of $45^\circ$, you know $CD$. Then as given answer suggests, drop perp from $A$ to $CD$, what is that given $OF = 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: drop the altitude $AH$ from $A$ to $DC$. What is the length of $AH$? What are the angles in $\triangle DAH$?Can you calculate the area of parallelogram knowing the base and the height?